# How can we define path more than one in Jfrog aql language spec file?

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli, artifactory-query-lang, jfrog-container-registry

Here below the defined spec file, I want to add more values in the "path": {$match}function. I mean I need to define more than one path in this syntax is that possible? i.e.: Test/dev , Test/qa , Test/prod etc..

```
  "files": [
    {
      "aql": {
        "items.find": {
          "repo": "Testing",
          "path": {"$match":"Test/dev"},
          "name": {"$match":"*"},
          "type": "file",
          "$or": [
            {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "created": { "$before":"90d" }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add them in the "or" clause:

```json
{
  "files": [
    {
      "aql": {
        "items.find": {
          "repo": "Testing",
          "name": { "$match": "*" },
          "type": "file",
          "created": { "$before": "90d" },
          "$or": [{ "$match": "Test/dev" }, { "$match": "Test/qa" }]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Read more:

1. [AQL documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Query+Language)
2. [Using File Specs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-UsingFileSpecs)